# Change Matplotlib Font in Linux setting

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, ubuntu, graph

I got a problem with matplolib, when I want change font on matplotlib at Linux(Ubuntu Distribution) Server.
It didnot display Chinese or other non-ascii characters in matplotlib.
I using the following step to find matplotlib font folder

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())
```

Then download the SimHei.tff in matplotlib/font/tff folder
change the setting in matplotlibrc

Here is the problem when i try to rebuild using

```
from matplotlib.font_manager import _rebuild
_rebuild()
```

it shows the following error msg:

```
AttributeError:module 'matplotlib.font_manager' has no attribute '_rebuild'
```

Comment: That function was removed. This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647041/9987623

Comment: Check out my answer for a similar question: [it is using matplotlib.font_manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336997/change-font-for-both-labels-and-ticks-on-3d-surface-plot/73341464#73341464)